# I am trying to make an FPS soccer game using Unity, but my script isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I am trying to create a soccer game from scratch... all I have done until now, is setting up the ball. This is how I want it to work: When the player collides with the ball, the ball jumps forward a bit. If you start running the ball will be pushed further away.

Now, here is my script for the ball (I am using the standard FPSController as character):

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class BallController : MonoBehaviour {

     private Rigidbody rb;

     public GameObject character;
     public float moveSpeed = 1000;
     public float shootSpeed = 2000;

     bool isTurnedUp = false;
     bool isTurnedDown = false;
     bool done = false;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void FixedUpdate () {

         //Debug.Log(isTurnedUp + ", " + isTurnedDown);

         switch (character.GetComponent<UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson.FirstPersonController>().m_IsWalking)
         {
             case true:
                 if (isTurnedUp == false)
                 {
                     moveSpeed = moveSpeed / 1.4f;
                     isTurnedUp = true;
                     isTurnedDown = false;
                 }
                 break;

             case false:
                 if (isTurnedDown == false)
                 {
                     moveSpeed = moveSpeed * 1.4f;
                     isTurnedDown = true;
                     isTurnedUp = false;
                 }
                 break;
         }
     }

     void Update()
     {

         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
         {     
             if (Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, character.transform.position) <= 5)
             {
                 float distance = Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, character.transform.position);
             }
         }

     }


     void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {

         FixedUpdate();
         if (done == false) {
             rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
             done = true;
         }
         else {

             done = false;

         }      
     }     

     //other
     void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
     {
         Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
         Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, 2);
     }
 }
```

My problem is that the ball doesn't behave how I want it... it feels like it's about luck if the ball will jump forward when I touch it. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling FixedUpdate?

Comment: Remove the `FixedUpdate` call from `OnCollisionEnter`.  `FixedUpdate` is called automatically every physics calculation.

Comment: Also do you want the ball to always go forward on the world axis or should it be going forward based off of where it was collided with?  `rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse)` is always world forward.

Comment: I want it to move in the direction negative from where it was collided. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your `done` seems a bit redundant what all can collide with this? if a 2 players hit the ball the first 1 will be false the second 1 will be true... so that is a bit weird to.

Comment: All I want for now, is just ONE PLAYER (me) to move the ball.

Comment: As @Eddge mentioned, you probably don't need the `done` flag.  The way it is used right now just makes it so that the ball will only be kicked every other time it is collided with.

Comment: Ok I removed the 'done'.

Comment: Did that at least resolve the randomness of the kicks being registered?

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't... I think the problem is something else.

Comment: Add a `Debug.Log('test")` message inside of `OnCollisionEnter`. Does it print every time the ball is successfully kicked? Does it print even when the ball is not kicked?

Comment: I did that, and I think I know what the problem is... the ball is colliding with the ground and the walls, and just keeps accelerating... how can i fix that?

Comment: You should try avoiding calling `GetComponent()` over and over. Instead put it in the `Awake()` function and save the component. `FirstPersonController controller; void Awake() { controller = character.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>(); }` then in your switch you do `controller.m_IsWalking` (btw you should probibly change the switch to a if-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `OnCollisionEnter` you need to ensure the ball can only be kicked by the player. You can check whether or not the player has collided with the ball by checking the name or tag of the collision. The following example uses the name and assumes your player GameObject is named "Player".

Remove the `done` flag since this will only allow the player to kick the ball every other time they collide, and remove the `FixedUpdate()` call since `FixedUpdate()` is already called automatically every physics calculation.

Finally, if you want to kick the ball away from the player, then you need to calculate the direction away from the collision point instead of using `Vector3.forward` as seen below.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        Vector3 direction = (collision.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
        rb.AddForce(-direction * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have much experience in that area but I don't believe you need to write any code to get your ball to bounce off of other rigidbodies. The physics should take care of that.  This [short tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/bouncing-ball) should make it clear.

Comment: And one more question, how do I push the ball forward globally when I touch it, and not locally. Because the ball spins, and the local positions change!

Comment: `Vector3.forward` is the vector defined by (0,0,1). Is your ball always traveling in the same direction when your player touches it regardless of angle?

Comment: No, it isn't... that is why I asked. How can I make the ball move, negatively from where it was touched?

Comment: Try replacing what's currently in the if statement with the following 2 lines:  `Vector3 direction = (collision.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;` and `rb.AddForce(-direction * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);`

Comment: I am sorry, which lines exactly please?

Comment: Replace `rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);` from my answer with the 2 lines of code from my previous comment. It is untested. If it doesn't work I can play around with it later when I am at my pc.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I will update the answer with the code from the previous comments.

Comment: Ok, I know, this is ridiculous :P : but there is another small problem... sometimes (only when I run), the ball just jumps forward with 4x the normal force, so I debugged it, and I saw that it just runs the OnCollisionEnter() 4 times, do you have any idea how to fix this @Alex Myers? Thank you so much AGAIN!

Comment: Are there multiple colliders attached to your player that could be overlapping it at once? If the answer is yes then what you'll want to do is isolate one of those colliders as its own object. So maybe create a child on your player and call it "Foot". Attached a single collider to that object that you want to be responsible for kicking the ball. Then instead of checking for "Player" when a collision is detected, check for "Foot" instead.

Comment: No, I didn't create bodyparts, it's still an invisible object. All I have is a character controller, and a capsule collider.

Comment: I believe the problem is that you have two rounded objects that are interacting at multiple contact points.  Try implementing what they did in the highest rated solution [here](http://answers.unity.com/answers/739063/view.html).

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems that it only happens when I am running sideways (I haven't implemented sideways running for the ball yet).

Comment: Alright. Sorry, but I think you should create a new question with those details included.